# Need some references on sound quality evaluation and syncing

Tags: speech-processing, reference-request, audio-processing, synchronization

I have to do a project where I'm receiving the same sound signal from different channels (with different offsets), but they may not be consistent all the time. At any given time, I should decide which channel is providing the best transmission, and make the connection as persistent as possible.

I'm an electronic engineering student familiar with related concepts. I appreciate it if you know of any reference that would help me.

Comment: Is it speech signals? Most common quality metric for speech would be [PESQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESQ) or some derivative. Not sure if it's applicable in your scenario.

Comment: Yeah it is! Thanks, I would check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I take it you are looking for speech quality measures. As far as I know, there exist a couple of objective measures, along with subjective procedures, since quality of speech is kind of a vague concept which may not be the same to everyone.

Since your application seems to require automatic evaluation, there are a number of measures you might want to check out:

- ITU-T Rec. P 835 for assessment of listening speech quality (no available reference signal)
- The PESQ for listening speech quality, mentioned by Florian already (when the reference signal is available)
- The PEAQ for assessment of audio quality (when the reference signal is available)
- The E-model für conversational speech quality (network parameters available)

All of these are listed in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-49127-9), along with a range of subjective measures. 
It seems to me that for your application, the [ITU-standard](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-P.563/en) is most reasonable since no clean reference signal is required.

Edit: What also may be of interest of you is the frequency-weighted segmental SNR (fwsegSNR), which incorporates the articulation index (AI). This measure apparently correlates well with subjective measures.

An overview of objective speech quality measures is also given in [this Loizou paper available online](https://ecs.utdallas.edu/loizou/speech/obj_paper_jan08.pdf).